# GridSearchCV fitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm having problems to fit my classifier using binarized labels.

```
clf_linear = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight='balanced'),
                      param_grid, cv=5)

clf_linear = clf_linear.fit(X_train_pca, y_train)
```

y_train was binarized by the following method:

```
y_train = label_binarize(y_train, classes=[1, 2, 3])
```

I got the following error:

File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 788, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (545, 3)

The input label shape is (682, 3) not (545, 3).

My professor told me to use binarized labels in gridSearchCV, but reading scikit-learn docs I think I can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter its 682,3 or 545,3. Why the target has 3 columns? Your y (targets) should be 1-d array for SVC. You dont need to do the `label_binarize` operation. Keep `y_train` as it is.

Doing this:

```
y_train = label_binarize(y_train, classes=[1, 2, 3])
```

Will convert the y_train to `label-indicator` matrix. That is used for multi-label classification problems (where the sample can have more than one class at a time). Its not used for multi-class problems.

Keep the `y_train`  as it is to keep it as one-dimensional array and `SVC` will handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you @Vivek, I was trying to do this because my roc curve seems to be strange and talking with my professor he suggested me to do this. The roc curve is not as smooth as he wants it to be.

Comment: @ArthurBernardo ROC curve is defined for binary tasks. So you will need to convert your multi-class problem into binary class so doing `label_binarize` is correct here. Internally SVC does the same. But for that, you will need to use `OneVsRestClassifier` to handle that. Simply using one-hot encoded labels turns on multi-label classification, which is not supported by `SVC`. Have you seen this:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#multiclass-settings ?

Comment: Yes, I saw this topic. I'm plotting ROC curve like this. The result is this graphic [link](http://prntscr.com/ln82n1). Do you see something wrong with these curves? I'm classifying the three faces with more samples in this dataset [link](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/). My doubt is if this curves should be more smooth. Thanks again for your help @VivekKumar.